# A word for both "payer" and "payee"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm working on making a ledger app that shows transactions. The focus is always on a single ledger, so transactions have a positive or negative amount, which raises or lowers the ledger's balance. However, we have a hard reference to the "other party ledger," to which, or from which money moved.

I'm having a hard time coming up with a word for the header that describes this column, since it could be the payee or the payer.

E.g.,

| Date | Description | ???? | Amount | Running Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | Initial account funding | checking account 1234 | +100 | 100 |
| 2021-01-02 | Transfer to John Doe | john.doe.1234 | -50 | 50 |
| 2021-01-03 | Transfer from Jane Doe | jane.doe.5678 | +25 | 75 |

I'd like to avoid using the word "account" since it has a different meaning elsewhere in the app, and "Payer/Payee" seems confusing since it doesn't indicate when one applies vs the other.

Comment: Why have one column for two things? Are you not allowed to leave blanks or something?

Comment: Without researching, my gut reaction would be to use "Third Party Account" for the heading, although the answers below are equally valid, and even more specific.

Comment: Choosing names for software elements is specifically offtopic according to our [help]. Please do not ask us for help naming your software elements.

Comment: @tchrist I definitely want to avoid breaking the rules, but I cannot find where that's specifically listed. Can you please show me? To be clear, seeking a word that conveys information to people via an interface is entirely different from "programming variable/class" that is mentioned. Nothing else is mentioned about software.

Comment: @xdumaine [But please, don’t ask any questions about the following topics. They are out of scope for this site. … • Naming, including naming programming variables/classes](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Yeah, I'm firmly in disagreement. I'm not asking about programming variables or classes. There's a meta question about this topic here - https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11630/questions-about-user-interface-design-wording

Comment: "If it is fundamentally about English, then whether UI comes into play as well is irrelevant." - I'm fundamentally asking about the English language, i.e., searching for a word to describe payer/payee in a nondirectional context.

Comment: If you already call it the “other party ledger” then why not label it “Other Party”?

Answer (score 2):

How about **counterparty**:

> an opposite party in a contract or financial transaction.
>
> -- Oxford Languages

Another dictionary gives [this example](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/counterparty):

> The counterparty to the option buyer is the option writer.

Answer (score 2):

***To/from*** would be a reasonable column header here. It doesn't necessarily call to mind a financial transaction specifically, but it's a common way to describe an act where one could be on either the giving or receiving end.

Comment: Absolutely, This would be the right accounting terminology. Short for: payment to and payment from.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a word like ***Agent*** would work.

> One that acts or exerts power
>
> - Merriam-Webster

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the combination "*creditor/debtor*" is right for heading that column.

> ([Clear Books](https://www.clearbooks.co.uk/blog/what-is-a-creditor-and-what-is-debtor/))
> What is a creditor?
> A creditor is a term used in accounting to describe an entity (can either be a person, organisation or a government body) that is owed money, as they have provided goods or services to another entity. Sometimes, this entity will charge interest on money borrowed as a way to make money. This could be interest on bank loan repayments or credit card payments.
>
> What is a debtor?
>
> A debtor is a term used in accounting to describe the opposite of a creditor — an individual that owes money, or who is in debt to an organisation or person. For example, a debtor is somebody who has taken out a loan at a bank for a new car.

So, John Doe is a creditor (to the account) and Jane Doe a debtor.